# Center div vertical, works fine with webkit but bug in firefox

Tags: css, webkit, gecko

I have a problem centering div in Firefox, it seems to work fine in all webkit browsers, so I dont really know what I'm doing wrong:

**My CSS:**

```
html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

body {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#Page {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
}

#LoginBackground {
position: absolute;
margin-top: -45%;
margin-left: -35%;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
width: 70%;
height: 90%;
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<body>
<div id="Page">
<div id="LoginBackground">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Is this a bug within the Gecko engine or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT
new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FsjNu/2/

```
html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

body {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#Page {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

#LoginBackground {
border: 1px solid red;
height: 90%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -35%;
position: absolute;
top: 5%;
width: 70%;
```

}

```
<body>
<div id="Page">
<div id="LoginBackground">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I dont think I provided enough information. Your answer is correct, but not enough for my problem. thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal align works fine for me, vertical seems to be the problem, try this, maybe.

```
#loginBackground
{
top:0;
margin-top: 5%;
}
```

Comment: didnt help. check out my example here [link](http://davidgreiner.dyndns.org/usocial/login.html)

Comment: Well, it works with top: 0 & margin-top 5%, but the footer goes over the red div, so you need to substract the footer height (10%) to your red div height.

Comment: Yeah I got you now. I think I will try a different approach. thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

use 
    #page{
    width:980px;
    margin:10px auto;
    }
    #LoginBackground{
    margin:50px auto;
    width:500px;
    }

Comment: I dont want a fixed width, the design should be liquid.

Comment: liquid as in what should it re size according to browser window or should its width depend on width of elements inside it

Comment: resize with the browser window